# Populate Excel Form Fields from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, file

I have an existing Form and I need to populate the fields directly from the MySQL database.

My boss wanted our client's profile tax computations to be automatically be entered to the Excel Form.

Any suggestion about this?

Thanks in advance...

BTW, with the use of PHP

Answer (score 1):

**SECOND EDIT:**

```
<?php

    function connect_db($db_name) {

        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_pass');
        $seldb = mysql_select_db($db_name);

        if($con && $seldb) {

            return true;

        }
        else {

            return false;

        }

    }

    function get_data_from_mysql() {

        $data_query = "SELECT date, new_users, old_users, income FROM stats ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30";

        $data_mysql = mysql_query($data_query);

        $data_finished = array();
        while($data_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_mysql)) {

            $data_finished[] = $data_fetch;

        }

        return $data_finished;

    }

    function print_to_xls($filename, $data_from_mysql) {

        $file = "xls_archive/" . $filename . ".xls";
        $file_abs_path = "http://www.yoursite.com/xls_archive/" . $file;
        $content = "date\t new users\t old users\t income\n";;

        foreach($data_from_mysql as $data) {

            $content .= $data['date'] . "\t " . $data['new_users'] . "\t " . $data['old_users'] . "\t " . $data['income'] . "\n";

        }

        $saving_file = $file;
        $fo = fopen($saving_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $data_to_write = $content;
        fwrite($fo, $data_to_write);
        fclose($fo);

        header("Content-type: application/ms-excel");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file);

        readfile($file_abs_path);

    }

    $connect_to_db = connect_db("db_name");

    if ($connect_to_db) {

        $data_to_print = get_data_from_mysql();

        $today = date("Y_m_d");
        $filename = "dailyreport_" . $today;

        print_to_xls($filename, $data_to_print);

    }
    else {

        print "ERROR";

    }

?>
```

Code above will produce an .xls from file generated from MySQL database.
* code is not tested but I think it perfectly works...

**FIRST EDIT:**

You can also do it by hand, by packing data in tabular format and change headers to excel ones like this:

```
$file ="dailyreport.xls";
$content = "data1 \t data2 \t data3 \t \n";

header("Content-type: application/ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file);

print $content;
```

This code will (after generating) prompt user to download file "dailyreport.xls"

Also you can try this php library to produce xls documents:
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Good answer, you could also use `$content = "<table><tr><td>data1</td>...` etc

Comment: May I know which file should I add this code of yours? Is it on the index.php?

Comment: That is more a question for you :) how do you organize your code... If you want me to help you please be more specific on what is desired procedure for generating xls with php...

Comment: Ah, sorry for that. Here's a sample of what I'm talking about: http://www.bookkeeper.ph/our-services/bir-forms/1601-e    but in contrast, if my client logged-in on my site and clicked the BIR Form 1601-E  command on the menu, MySQL will automatically retrieve their Company profile and fill up the fields on the form.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Code that I wrote should point you in the right direction. Just modify database connection function and query to fit your table structure and try it. Make directory "xls_archive" in public_html before you try script. I did not tested the code but it should work immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use PHP to get data from MySQL but showing up in Excel can be done in many ways, lets assume you have a procedure which will talk to mysql and get the required data and its in XML format.

Now you can do an Export to excel, ideally what you do here is change the response type to application/vnd.ms-excel and format the data in a tabular format so that excel will treat it as rows and columns.

well the above is one way, there are many other ways, you can generate the excel at the backend and provide the user with a link, or you can expose the data as a service and write an  excel addon to read the data from your service

Comment: That's simple you don't need an excel object for this, you need to build a tabular format via php and set the response content type to excel and it will prompt user to download excel file

Comment: Please upload a screenshot somewhere , I'm commenting from mobile so cannot see the zip file

Answer (score 0):

Create the whole form as an html table, without form fields, then serve the content as an excel spread sheet.

This answer gives more details

[HTML table to excel - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437745/html-table-to-excel-php)

You'll get a security warning every time you open the spreadsheet, but as you're the one who created it, and it's for internal use, you can ignore the security warning.

The warning will say something like...

`"The file you are trying to open, '[filename]', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file?"`

Also see [What's XLSHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322479/whats-xlshtml)

Comment: I was suggested by others to use fpdf that will create a template with the use of pdf form and that's the time where I will be able to add fields to create a php form.

Comment: If you're outputting to an xls, then every cell is effectively an input field, in that you can use the values in calcs on the spreadsheet and change them on the spreadsheet. Do you want "form controls" in your spreadsheet?